# RoR Project: "bundle install" fails on sqlite3 under cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cygwin, rubygems

I am starting the RoR 3 Video Tutorial, doing the windows installation using cygwin on win7.  Everything has worked, I have installed rails 3.0.1, and created a test project successfully.  The error occurs when I run `bundle install` from within this newly created test project (see paste below).

```
$ bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
which: no sudo in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdriv
e/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Windo
wsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Dell/DW WLAN Card:/cygdrive/c/Progra
m Files (x86)/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x8
6)/Java/jre6/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin:/cygdrive/c/wamp/bin/
php/php5.3.4:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem:/cygdrive/c/Prog
ram Files (x86)/Calibre2:/cygdrive/c/xampp/php)
Using rake (0.9.2)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.1)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.4.2)
Using activemodel (3.0.1)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.3)
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Using tzinfo (0.3.29)
Using actionpack (3.0.1)
Using mime-types (1.16)
Using polyglot (0.3.2)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.2.19)
Using actionmailer (3.0.1)
Using arel (1.0.1)
Using activerecord (3.0.1)
Using activeresource (3.0.1)
Using bundler (1.0.18)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.0.1)
Using rails (3.0.1)
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.4) with native extensions       0 [main] ruby 22696 C:\c
ygwin\bin\ruby.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\cygwin\lib\ruby\1.8
\i386-cygwin\etc.so to same address as parent: 0x1B0000 != 0x2F0000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
023F4B88  6102796B  (023F4B88, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
023F4E78  6102796B  (6117EC60, 00008000, 00000000, 61180977)
023F5EA8  61004F1B  (611A7FAC, 61243684, 001B0000, 002F0000)
End of stack trace
      1 [main] ruby 20008 fork: child 22696 - died waiting for dll loading, errn
o 11
      0 [main] ruby 15396 C:\cygwin\bin\ruby.exe: *** fatal error - unable to re
map \\?\C:\cygwin\lib\ruby\1.8\i386-cygwin\etc.so to same address as parent: 0x2
20000 != 0x290000
      0 [main] ruby 11608 fork: child 15396 - died waiting for dll loading, errn
o 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found another post that answered this.  Simply had to rebaseall as described here:

https://superuser.com/questions/231590/running-rebaseall-on-cygwin